# Ошибка: "Found non-callable @@iterator" nuxt

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Когда отправляю запрос на сервер, то получаю 500 код с ошибкой: `Found non-callable @@iterator`.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Отправка данных на сервер**

```
    async change({ commit }, { token, fd, orderId }) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`${serv}/orders/change`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Accept-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ updates: fd, orderId })
        });

        const { ok, message, orders } = await res.json();

        if (ok) {
          commit("setOrders".orders);
        }

        return { ok, message, orders };
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    },
```

**Получение данных на сервере**

```
router.post("/change", isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.isAdmin) {
      const { orderId, updates } = req.body;

      await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(orderId, ...updates);

      return res.status(200).json({ ok: true, message: "Заказ изменен" });
    } else {
      return res.status(403).json({ ok: false, message: "У вас нет доступа" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    return res.status(500).json({ ok: false, message: "Произошла ошибка сервера" });
  }
});
```

Comment: А что конкретно сервер вернул? Это ошибка js.

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, он возвращает 500 код - ошибка на стороне сервера ({ok: false, message: 'Произошла ошибка сервера'})

Comment: `updates` - у вас скорее всего объект. А его нельзя проитерировать

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, да, спасибо. Это решило проблему!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я использовал spread оператор у объекта `updates`

Вместо этого

```
await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(orderId, ...updates);
```

Написал так

```
await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(orderId, updates);
```